# How to randomly choose a SKSpriteNode?

Tags: swift, random

I want to choose from 4 enemies using random and present it on scene. For that purpose I've made this:

```
func enemyPicker() -> SKSpriteNode {
    var enemyArray = [mouse, robot, drone, block, bird]
    var countArray = UInt32(enemyArray.count)
    var pickOneEneny = arc4random_uniform(countArray)
    var randomElement = Int(pickOneEnemy)

    return enemyArray.randomElement
}
```

But Xcode says to me that `SKSpriteNode does not have a member named randomElement`. And it surely doesn't, but how would I say to my function that I need it to pick and assign that random Int to an actual enemy from array?

I tried to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157647/how-to-choose-a-random-skshapenode-from-an-array-using-arc4random) but it's not working for me. I also tried to change -> SKSpriteNode to SKTexture, String and "T" and had not any luck with it.

My SpriteNodes are declared like:

```
var mouse = SKSpriteNode() 
let mouseAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "mouse")
var mouseArray = [SKTexture]()
mouseArray.append(mouseAtlas.textureNamed("mouse_0"));
mouseArray.append(mouseAtlas.textureNamed("mouse_1"));
mouseArray.append(mouseAtlas.textureNamed("mouse_2"));

mouse = SKSpriteNode(texture: mouseArray[0]);
self.mouse.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 138)
self.mouse.size = CGSizeMake(self.mouse.size.width, self.mouse.size.height + mouse.size.height / 2)

self.mouse.name = "mouse"
self.addChild(mouse)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func enemyPicker() -> SKSpriteNode {
    let enemyArray = [mouse, robot, drone, block, bird]
    return enemyArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(enemyArray.count)))]
}
```

Comment: it says that `Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments`. Why?

Comment: You need to show how you have declared your spritenodes (mouse, robot, etc...)

Comment: I don't understand, that should be a really simple stuf and everywhere I go - I have an error or two.